# Expected type 'dict', for 'str' instead PyCharm. Trying to convert all PDF pages into CSV using tabula?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pycharm, tabula, tabula-py

my code can convert only one upper part of my PDF first sheet, when I am tying to convert all pages I can't  because I get the error in my code.

```
import tabula

tabula.convert_into("/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/KH_Profilansicht_13.11.2019-2.pdf", "/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/test.csv", output_format="csv",pages='all')
```

The error which I get is about the pages function

when I am writing it PyCharm says **Expected type 'dict', for 'str' instead**

I am using python 3.x version in my PyCharm.

Is there other ways how to choose all pages to convert not only upper side of first page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a runtime error? PyCharm complain is just a warning one can "safely" ignore. The problem is `tabula.convert_into` has an incorrect docstring type annotation:

```
kwargs (dict)
```

should be e.g.

```
kwargs (str)
```

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values